# How do I catch the event when my firefox extension is uninstalled?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a Firefox extension and I need to send myself a callback when it is uninstalled. Is there a callback for a Firefox extension uninstall?

I am looking for something analogous to chromes [onUninstalled event](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#event-onUninstalled).

Comment: Yes I think you are right, this is what i was looking for: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonListener#onUninstalling()) , is there a way to close out a duplicate question?

Comment: I already marked it as a duplicate, it now needs four more close votes. Feel free to flag it as a duplicate.